# formatting problem, why is this error not going away?

Tags: c

I am not understanding what the bug is. Maybe a segmentation fault? I am suppose to get this code to work then figure out how to make it faster. below is the error code. I am currently debugging it on GDB online .

ain.c:26:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZEOFLIST 1000000000


int is_sorted(int values[], int length);
void quicksort(int* numbers, int low, int high);
int partition(int* vals, int low, int high);
void swap(int *a, int *b);

int main() {
    
int itemsSale = 0;
int minCharge = 0;
int *list;

    // Allocate space for our list.
list = (int*)malloc(SIZEOFLIST*sizeof(int));

scanf("%d%d", &itemsSale, &minCharge);

for(int i =0 ; i < itemsSale; i++){
    scanf("%d", list[i]);
}
   
   quicksort( list, 0, minCharge-1 );
   
   free(list);
   
   return 0;
}

void quicksort(int* numbers, int low, int high) {

    // Only have to sort if we are sorting more than one number
    if (low < high) {
        int split = partition(numbers,low,high);
        quicksort(numbers,low,split-1);
        quicksort(numbers,split+1,high);
    }
}

int partition(int* vals, int low, int high) {

    int temp;
    int i, lowpos;

    // Pick a random partition element and swap it into index low.
    i = low + rand()%(high-low+1);
    swap(&vals[low], &vals[i]);

    // Store the index of the partition element.
    lowpos = low;

    // Update our low pointer.
    low++;

    // Run the partition so long as the low and high counters don't cross.
    while (low <= high) {

        // Move the low pointer until we find a value too large for this side.
        while (low <= high && vals[low] <= vals[lowpos]) low++;

        // Move the high pointer until we find a value too small for this side.
        while (high >= low && vals[high] > vals[lowpos]) high--;

        // Now that we've identified two values on the wrong side, swap them.
        if (low < high)
           swap(&vals[low], &vals[high]);
    }

    // Swap the partition element into it's correct location.
    swap(&vals[lowpos], &vals[high]);

    return high; // Return the index of the partition element.
}

// Swaps the values pointed to by a and b.
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
     int temp = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: `#define SIZEOFLIST 1000000000` Assuming `sizeof(int) = 4`, then do you really need __4 GB__ of memory for your program?

Comment: `scanf("%d", list[i]);` --> `scanf("%d", &list[i]);` `list[i]` is an `int`. The error says it needs an `int *`, not an `int`. `scanf` format of `%d` requires a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Seems to be a homework/etc question, so that size is probably part of "then figure out how to make it faster".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to read an int by using scanf, then scanf doesn't need the value of the int, it needs its address. Printing would need the value, but scanf needs to know where to store the value that it reads, so it needs int*.

And that's exactly what the compiler is telling you: You passed an int, but you need to pass an int*.

Comment: thanks you cleared my confusion with a different matter.

Comment: numbers/coding are interesting... especially when people are asked about them.